# CollectionView is not displaying vertically as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to implement following screen.

[image: Expected Output]

But in my code, it is displaying following way

[image: My Output]

following code I wrote,

```
    import UIKit

class LunchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}

extension LunchViewController:UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate {


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 412, height: 180)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // return self.myLibraryArray.count
        return 8
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // let item = self.myLibraryArray[indexPath.row]

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RestaurantCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? RestaurantCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        //cell.fillDetails(item)
        return cell

    }


}
```

[Here is the complete project link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tGRHrCrJUNiy1KuZY5s1r68oxfiNv_3F/view?usp=sharing)

Can any one tell me, what is the issue? or what I have to write the code to get expected output?

**Update**:

[image: some white Seperator is showing]

Comment: You are setting your item size width to 412. Try changing the `sizeForItemAt` to something like `collectionView.frame.size.width` and it should be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select `collectionView` and Change Estimate Size to `none`. In storyboard.
if you dont want space between two cells then set `0` to `for lines` in `Min spacing`

[image]

And i have given `width` as screen width

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 180)
}
```

Output :-

[image]

Comment: excellent, its working but small white seperator is showing now

Answer (score 2):

Change `sizeForItem` method to this:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 180)
}
```

Also, make sure the `mainCollectionView` is constrained to the leading and trailing edges in the storyboard.

Comment: Check constraints as I've mentioned. Check both leadingAnchor and trailingAnchor